# Is there a way in Laravel 5.4 I can save unisharp filemanager standalone image?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way I can save unisharp standalone image file name in my model and then get in edit form?

I want to make featured image for my articles model. I want to get that featured image in unisharp filemanager standalone button when I click and get select previous uploaded image i want to save that image name in my model articles.

And how can I call that image path in my edit form articleController.

I want something like Wordpress. Select featured image if previous uploaded or upload new one and select it.

Something like that. I think you get the point.

Comment: I don't know who's spreading word that there is a site in internet where people work for free.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a field for the image in your table and its model, the field should be in `$fillable` array

according to unisharp docs the stand alone button should be like this filling the proper input right ?

```
 <button type="button" id="lfm-image" data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder">Choose Image</button>

 <img id="holder"src="{{isset($model->image) ? :''}}">

 <input type="hidden" id="thumbnail" name="filepath">
```

Then you get it in the controller like this

```
 if ($request->filepath != null) {

        $page->image = $request->filepath;
        $page->save();
 }
```

It works like charm in edit form as well